# Prove that $\sum_{x=0}^{\lambda - 1}(\frac{\lambda^{x+1}}{x!}-\frac{\lambda ^x}{(x-1)!})=\frac{\lambda^\lambda}{(\lambda - 1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{\lambda - 1}\left(\frac{\lambda^{x+1}}{x!}-\frac{\lambda ^x}{(x-1)!}\right)=\frac{\lambda^\lambda}{(\lambda - 1)!}$.

I think I need to write it in the derivative of something and then exchange the sum and derivative. I can't use the binomial theorem as the sum is from $x=0$ to $\lambda - 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $T_r=\frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{r!}$

the $n$th term of your series is $T_n-T_{n-1}$ which itself clearly forms a [Telescopic Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)